# iPhone 6s restarts - apple offers a "new one" (refurbished) as exchange solution

Tags: restart, iphone, applecare

After having my iPhone 6s locked for 2-3 hours, sporadically (once per week) it presents the following problem:

- No response to home button
- After pressing 1-2 times for 2-3 seconds the unlock button it shows black screen and the white "waiting circle" for 5-10 seconds
- It comes back to life but every time this happens it is also asking the Pin for the sim card.

I would not consider this as a restart or that the phone shuts down and it just starts again because when this happens it does not show the apple sign that normally shows up when the iPhone is completely restarted.

I took the iPhone to Apple 3 times. We tried "reset all" etc but the problem consists and I also have problems with logging in/out in the iTunes (it freezes).

So this is where Apple offered me a refurbished iPhone. They started by telling me that it is new and when I saw the different case and started asking questions then they told me that the Battery, housing, motherboard, screen is new but it might contain old parts too.

Does someone have had the same experience with the turning circle.

And would you recommend taking the refurbished from Apple? Bad experiences with refurbished phones from Apple stores? They give warranty 3 months, which is 1 more month than mine. (my warranty expires in September)

Answer (score 2):

### Apple refurbished phones work great.

I actually use one right now, since the battery on my old phone had expanded. These phones have been tested well to make sure there's nothing wrong with them. Sure, you might get a recycled camera, but you'll never know. My phone was good as new when I got it, and I am still happy with it to this day.

The three-month warranty will cover any problems that a refurbished phone may have - bad battery, touchscreen, etc will be covered in that.

If you'd like to keep all your data, you can simply do an iTunes backup (not necessarily to your own computer as it is freezing), then restore that backup to your new phone.

Also, your phone is respringing (not rebooting)

Comment: I would second the "repair parts" and Apple official refurbished parts are in most cases better than new. The new parts get tested, but the "refurbished service part" is what Apple gives to someone when their new iPhone fails 30 days into service. My feeling is Apple understands that repair parts need to be better than new since you already had a less than good experience which is why you need a service part. There are far fewer service parts as well - so they can be tested more thoroughly than the millions of new parts. I could be wrong, but that's my experience.

Answer (score 0):

I bought a macbook from Apple - refurbished : looked absolutely new, perfect, came with 1 year warranty. Been fine. IMHO their refurbished is better than others new.... But your choice.